# Can you send SMS files in Android AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When communicating with an android AVD, can you send files or images/videos within an SMS?

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not possible. Sending MMS is not available on AVD.

Comment: Do you know a way I can attempt the stagefright exploit on virtual software if AVD is not an option?

Answer (score -1):

You can send SMS, but why you need image or videos in sms? I think you have a wrong concepts about android. But... if you need send a SMS use this:

- open a console
- connect via telnet to the running emulator: telnet localhost 5554
- type this: sms send senderPhoneNumber textmessage